# The output not shown in message passing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a google chrome extension project where content.js script sends message to popup.js. Also trying to get some text from content.js to be turned into the same thing but on popup.js. Here is all my code.

This is my manifest file.
manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "hoko's ext",
    "description": "my ext",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html" 
      },
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["https://*/*", "http://*/*"],
          "js": ["content-script.js"]
        }
      ],
      "background":  {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab"
      ]
  
}
```

This is the popup you get when you click on the icon in the toolbar.
popup.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>I am the popup</h1>


<p id="extensionpopupcontent"></p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my content script called content-script.js

```
function injectScript(file_path, tag) {
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('src', file_path);
    node.appendChild(script);
}

injectScript(chrome.runtime.getURL('inject.js'), 'body');


chrome.runtime.sendMessage(document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerText);
```

In background.js, I am receiving the message from content-script.js.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse) {
  function onMessage(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
    "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
    "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello") {
       sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    }
}
})
```

In popup.js, it is receiving from background.js to output the code from content-script.js.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
let bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();


    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, tabs => {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
            document.getElementById('extensionpopupcontent').innerHTML = response;
         });
    

});

});
```

I believe I need to inject this script that is inject.js.

```
function click() {
    return document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerText;
}

click();
```

Comment: Your question is a mess.
Try to edit and explain bettere what you want to achieve.
However: Why to declare statically a content script in manifest file where inside it you create a script you take from another js file?
Also, you cannot use chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() with manifest V3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. remove `background` and `content_scripts` in manifest.json
2. remove `tabs` from `permissions` in manifest.json
3. remove background.js, content-script.js, and inject.js
4. rewrite popup.js as follows:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, tabs => {
  document.getElementById('extensionpopupcontent').textContent = tabs[0]?.title;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked but I had to put activeTab in the permissions.